# Why doesn't obj ?? null cause an compiler warning

Tags: c#, compiler-warnings

In the case where reference type is coalesced with null, why isn't this a compiler warning in the C# compiler?  Is there any case where this makes sense?

```
obj2 = obj ?? null;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example doesn't exactly make sense but something like this does;

```
d = a ?? b ?? c ?? null;
```

Here, I'm saying taking the first non null value of the three, if they're all null then just take null.

Comment: What would be the difference to `d = a ?? b ?? c;`?

Comment: @DanielFischer functionally it's no different. I think the intent is more clear to the reader, especially if they're not very familiar with the null coalescing operator.

Comment: That's the conclusion I came to too, it's more explicit.

Answer (score 11):

You should read [my essay on the subject](https://web.archive.org/web/20190119002419/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/03/03/danger-will-robinson/).

Briefly: in order for a compiler warning to exist it has to be:

1. Thought of
2. Cheap to implement
3. Almost always wrong
4. Reasonably typed by accident
5. Eliminatable
6. Rare
7. Only capable of being done by the compiler
8. Not obvious upon testing

Your proposed warning does not meet requirements 1 and 4. You are, to my knowledge, the first person to think of this, and therefore it cannot be a warning because no one on the compiler team thought of it. And it is not likely to be typed by accident, so why should it be a warning? Warnings are there to tell you when you mistyped something that is *likely* to be mistyped. It also fails requirement 3, since the code is not obviously *wrong*, it's just *needlessly complicated*. The compiler does not give warnings for `x * 1` where `x` is an integer either.

Answer (score 7):

It makes *sense*, it just isn't very useful.

Neither is:

```
i = i + 0;
```

But the compiler doesn't complain about that either.
Why should it? The compiler does what it is told, as long as your request is syntactically correct - which it is.

Comment: Will this line be removed during optimization?

Comment: @Travis interesting question - I don't know, but it wouldn't *error*

Comment: A quick test in LINQPad looks like it does optimize out the addition if `i` is an `int`. (The IL for `i = i;` appears identical as `i = i + 0`) It's definitely smart enough not to optimize it out if `i` is a custom type with an implicit `+` operator overload for `int.` EDIT: It appears to keep the addition in if `i` is a `float` or `double` (but not `decimal`)

Comment: @Chris kudos for the attention to detail - more than I could stretch to on a Friday evening

Comment: Yes, the C# compiler will optimize away additions of constant zero to integers. It will also optimize away multiplications by constant one.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a lot of things that does not make sence, compiler does not have to point each one of them as a warning.

Answer (score 1):

Although the statement is not very useful, why would it warn you?

If `obj` is not null, `obj2` is assigned to `obj`.  Else `obj2` is assigned to `null`. This is perfectly legal.

Answer (score 1):

As [Eric Lippert said](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/01/25/why-are-unused-using-directives-not-a-warning.aspx),

> we try to reserve warnings for only those situations where we can say with almost certainty that the code is broken, misleading or useless

So warnings are used for code which, while being syntactically correct, can lead to real problems.